# Max heap size problem with node on windows

Tags: node.js

I am having problems configuring Node to run on my windows machine. I need to set the heap size to something larger than the default size, but when I try to do this, I end up with a heap size of about 3mb and the compile fails. I have tried 4gb and 8gb, with similar results.

I took a look around the net to see if anyone else is having the same problem, and there is a bug logged against this (https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3226). It isn't getting any attention, which seems odd, given how many people are using Node.

My Question: Has anyone else encountered this issue, and discovered a workaround? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this problem. The dev who set up node on the server mixed the builds, so there was a 32 bit build running in a 64 bit environment. Removing node and re-installing the correct version caused all the issues to go away.

If you see memory problems with your heap allocations, go double check that you are running the correct builds.